# Bash for loop isn't circling through array in anticipated manner

Tags: bash, loops

I have a variable 'roles' which contains the following data:

Constructor,Deconstructor,Transformer

I am circling through an array and I want to append a user name variable next to the role information, but I'm getting 'bad' results:

```
   echo $roles
   echo "$roles" 
   array=$(echo "$roles" | tr "," "\n")
   for i in $array
   do
      echo $user_id - "$i"
   done
```

My output however is coming out as this:

```
Constructor,Deconstructor,Transformer
Constructor,Deconstructor,Transformer
bman - Constructor
Deconstructor
Transformer
```

The output SHOULD look like the following:

```
bman - Constructor
bman - Deconstructor
bman - Transformer
```

Comment: It's working fine on my bash.

Answer (score 3):

`array=$(echo "$roles" | tr "," "\n")` does not create an array.

It creates three lines of text.

You wanted `array=($(echo "$roles" | tr "," "\n"))` but that will not work correctly if any of the fields contain spaces.

Even better than that would be to use:

```
IFS=, read -a array <<< "$roles"
```

which is safe for fields containing spaces.

Also `$array` is not how you get all the elements from an array. To do that you use `"${array[@]}"`.

Comment: How do I get it to work if there are fields with spaces?

Comment: @chepner I was in the middle of writing that but testing with literal newlines in `$roles` was causing me trouble.

Comment: @user3299633 chepner's version will work with fields with spaces. Though apparently not literal newlines and I'm a bit stumped by that fact at the moment.

Comment: `read` only reads up to the first newline; when the string has embedded newlines, you'll need to use `readarray -t <<< "$roles"`.

Comment: I should clarify that the confusion I was having was that using `-d ''` was tossing an extra newline at the end of the last field read from `"$roles"`. The fact that `read` stopped otherwise was not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and replace every comma by a whitespace:

```
roles="Constructor,Deconstructor,Transformer"
user_id="bman"
for i in ${roles//,/ }; do echo "$user_id $i"; done
```

Output:

```
bman Constructor
bman Deconstructor
bman Transformer
```